# Kanai's Cube powers and other legendary items

Tags: diablo-iii

I've been recently using the cube to extract legendary powers but I can't find information about the interaction with the power selected for a specific slot (weapon, armor or jewelry) and the presence of other legendary powers in the given slot.

E.g.:
I use Deathwish as weapon (+30/35% all damage while I channel Arcane Torrent, Disintegrate or Ray of frost)
I select Etched Sigil as power for the weapon slot in the cube (Arcane Torrent, Disintegrate and Ray of frost channeling alos use other Arcane Power Spenders)

Will the 2 sum up or I get only the cube one?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You will get both effects, and that is why they have the 3 slots available in Kanai's cube (weapon, armor, jewelry).

There will be affects that help each other, but I don't know if +X% effects are additive or multiplicative.  Either way, you want to choose Kanai cube effects that compliment your current build.  I would focus on increasing/reducing damage, as that's what the popular builds tend to focus on.

I would check out www.diablofans.com and check out builds on there and see how different effects work with each other.  For Wizard i tend to like Quin69's Flash Fire Wizard (http://www.diablofans.com/builds/70681-flash-fire-wizard-t10-speed).